# What's the purpose of `cl-lib` in emacs?

Tags: common-lisp

Why does emacs need the `cl-lib` Common Lisp compatibility?  What is it used for?

Comment: Who said that Emacs needs Common Lisp compatibility?

Comment: Originally, it was named `cl` and was used to add Common Lisp-like features to elisp. Today, it's named `cl-lib` and has a much higher ambition when it comes to Common Lisp compatibility. Unfortunately, due to this, plain elisp lack a lot of basic features, like `intersection`, which aren't available for us that don't want to import a busload of Common Lisp stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Emacs doesn't (or didn't<sup>1</sup>) *need* it, in the sense that everything in `cl-lib.el` is ultimately implemented in terms of standard Emacs Lisp, and therefore things *using* `cl-lib` could do the same.

That doesn't mean it's not *useful* to have lots of Common Lisp features available in Emacs (especially for Common Lisp programmers).

So it's a convenience (which many elisp authors gladly leverage).

<sup>1</sup> Notwithstanding that cl-lib macros are used in lots of standard Emacs code, so you couldn't *remove* `cl-lib` without rewriting a lot of code.  The rewrites would still be possible, though.

Comment: Interesting. Although my original question was going along the lines of "What does it do?". But I guess this more less answers it.